# .net 4.7.1 C# OCX event handler works on win10x 86/64, does not work on win7/8 x86/64

Tags: .net, windows, compatibility, eventhandler, ocx

The Backstory - Our company has a C# Click Once app that uses a .ocx file to register an event handler. The event handler's function is arbitrary, but in this case the event handler is performing a file operation on a file path that is returned. This OCX control is supplied by a 3rd party vendor. I do not have the source or the ability to edit the 3rd party OCX control.

The problem - The event handler I'm registering is never triggered on windows 7/8 x86/64. Windows 10 x86/64 works fine.

To make things more interesting, the event handlers are triggered on Windows 7/8 x86/64 after I install Visual Studio 2017. Same version of our app, does not work before VS2017 is installed, works after.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, targeting .net 4.7.1, and compiling for x86 on a 64 bit Windows 10 installation.

I have to assume that the Visual Studio 2017 installer is installing something on Windows 7/8 that allows the event handlers be called successfully, but I can't figure out what it is.

I have checked through the Event Logs and there is no error. An exception is not raised in the application when the event handler should be called, or when the event handler is registered.

The Questions -

1. Has anyone experienced something similar?
2. Were you able to resolve the issue?
3. How were you able to resolve this issue?

I have been pulling my hair out all week trying to address this, and I have exhausted all of the options that I know of. I would greatly appreciate the community's help on this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2017 installs .NET Framework 4.6 on windows 7 if that framework version is not there. If your app is working fine on windows 10 but not on windows 7 shows your app might require latest .NET framework version.

Comment: The problem i'm having is not that the app won't run. It is specifically with one portion of the application - receiving an event from a COM interop reference. I have also tried installing the .net framework 4.6 before re targeting the application to 4.7.1. No change in behavior was observed. Thank you for your comment, but this does not resolve the issue.